# Prove that a symmetric group $S_n$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

Prove that a symmetric group $S_n$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $n$.

I can see it for a symmetric group $S_3$ and $S_4$ but how can I generalize it for any number $n.$

Comment: Consider $\sigma:\{1,\ldots ,n\} \longrightarrow \{1,\ldots ,n\}$ defined by $\sigma(i)=i+1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $\sigma(n)=1$

Comment: The way you see it for $S_3$ and $S_4$ should tell you how to generalize to any $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The element $$(1,2,3,\dots, n)$$ has order $n$.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: Maybe because this is not just a hint. (Not my downvote.)

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that it gives too much away, @EthanBolker?

Comment: Well it does answer the question. In this case it would be hard to write a hint that didn't. Rather than answering for a new user, I'd have asked the OP to edit the question to tell us why they knew the answer for $n=3,4$ and to try to generalize. But I wouldn't have downvoted.

Comment: Noted, @EthanBolker. Thank you again.